# esint package changes integral to cap symbol

Tags: fonts

The following code produces wrong output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, esint, kpfonts}

\begin{document}
\[\int_a^b f(x) dx \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the loading order of the packages everything works:

```
\usepackage{kpfonts,esint}
```

[image]

Why is this happening? It seems such a simple case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a simple case (or it seems to be, see later on). The `esint` package overrides integral signs; but also `kpfonts` changes the default math fonts; so you want to override `kpfonts`, not the default math fonts and the order *must* be

```
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{esint}
```

The sad truth is that the two packages are incompatible, as they both define a math symbol font with the same name (which explains the bizarre symbol you get when using the wrong loading order): they both use the same identifier `largesymbolsA`.

Here's what happens.

1. If you load first `esint` and then `kpfonts`, the math symbol font declared by `kpfonts` overrides the one declared by `esint` with the same name. This font has different symbols than `esint`'s; since `kpfonts` doesn't redefine `\intop` (the command responsible for printing the integral sign), LaTeX will choose the corresponding slot in the font declared by `kpfonts`, which happen to have that strange symbol in it.
2. If you load first `kpfonts` and then `esint`, the `largesymbolsA` font defined by `kpfonts` will be overridden, so commands that rely on it will print random symbols.

In both cases you lose something.

Here's a workaround, but really `esint` should change the identifier for its symbol font. Maybe also `kpfonts` should, avoiding too generic names.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\let\ORG@DeclareSymbolFont\DeclareSymbolFont
\def\DeclareSymbolFont#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ORG@DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsesint}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
  \def\re@DeclareMathSymbol##1##2##3##4{%
    \let##1=\undefined
    \DeclareMathSymbol{##1}{##2}{largesymbolsesint}{##4}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{esint}

\makeatletter
\let\DeclareSymbolFont\ORG@DeclareSymbolFont
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\[\int_a^b f(x) dx \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really feel that some day CTAN/TUG/TeX.SX/etc. should organize a big treasure hunt for package conflicts, make a database of them and then start fixing them one at a time... I might even start learning TeX programming if there was a big "everybody fix TeX" initiative.